# What is the name of the music that plays when zoro has a flashback to fighting the humandrills during the fishman island arc?

Tags: one-piece

He asks Mihawk to train him and fights the humandrills then uses kokujo o tatsumaki afterwards.

Here is the clip https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=z-M8fD8m0To

Answer (score 1):

It is the central part of [**Zoro Theme**](https://youtu.be/SSftkNqh5-I?t=2m2s).